# Append to a specific type with a specific class

Tags: jquery

So like the title states i want to append data to a specific type (in my case a div) that has a specific class. My problem is, because i dont know if later down the line i'll add more items or not or use other divs or children with the same class i would like to avoid using :nth child methods. My code is below:

HTML

```
<form name="checkListForm">
        <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
    </form>
    <div id="button">Add!</div>
    <div class="list"></div>
```

JS/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();    
        $("").append(toAdd);
    })
});
```

Now in know the last line is lacking some code but thats the part i cant figure out. (im new to Jquery) On the button click i would like to add input to a list. I was thinking along the lines of

```
$("div").append(toAdd);
```

but that would add the input to all available divs.

Any extra explanation would be greatly apreciated!

---

I should probably add that for the ones that hadn't guessed already the added items need to go in the div with class="list"

Comment: Will the div you want to append the data to always be the next div after the button div? Is there a reason you can't use a unique ID to target the list div?

Comment: there is no way to tell, it might or it might not be but for the sake of asking lets assume its not.

Comment: So you want to be able to pick a specific element without that element having any uniquely identifying feature?

Comment: Yes, although i dont need it for any project i'm working on i'm curious if its possible to do (again without using :nth) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#button').click(function () {
           $('div.list').append($('input[name=checkListItem]').val());
       });

   });
```

It append to div content with the data of input with name attribute value checkListItem

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Comments added. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Follow the jquery doc:
https://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var toAdd = $("input[name=checkListItem]").clone().appendTo( ".list" );;
    })
});
```

But careful, you dont want the attribute name to be the same.